# Unit testing a directive with <select>

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have a directive called `<dimension>` that renders html:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives').
  directive('dimension', ['$rootScope', 'Dimension', function($rootScope, Dimension) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        inputs: '=inputsModel',
        url: '@',
        listenFor: '@',
        broadcastOnChange: '@'
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, Dimension) {
        this.get = function() {
          Dimension.get($attrs.url, $scope.inputs).then(function(data) {
            $scope.alloptions = data;
          });
        };
      },
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
        $controller.get();

        // Listen for changes to select, and broadcast those changes out to rootScope
        var dimension = $($element).find('select');
        dimension.on('change', function(event) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('DimensionDirective.change', $attrs.broadcastOnChange);
        });

        // Listen for the broadcast, and react if the value of the broadcast is in the listen-for attribute list
        $rootScope.$on('DimensionDirective.change', function(event, value) {
          if (value == $scope.listenForArray) {
            $controller.get();
          }
        });
      },
      template:
          '<div>' + 
            '<label ng-transclude></label>' +
            '<fieldset>' +
                '<div class="form-group">' +
                  '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="x for x in alloptions" multiple class="form-control"></select>' +
                '</div>' +
             '</fieldset>' +
          '</div>',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true
    };
  }]).
  factory('Dimension',
    ["$http", function($http) {
      return {
        get: function(_url, _inputs) {
          var future;
          future = $http({
            url: _url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: _inputs
          });
          return future.then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
          });
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

I now want to create a unit test to validate that there are the correct number of elements in the select, after they loaded from xhr.  I created a unit test that looks roughly like this:

```
describe('directive', function() {
  var $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('myApp.directives'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('url').
      respond(["Item 1", "Item 2"]);
  }));

  it('should load select\'s options from xhr on render', function() {
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      var element = $compile('<dimension ng-model="inputs.model" url="url">Dimension</dimension>')($rootScope);
      var select = element.find('select');
      expect(element.find('select').length).toBe(2); //TODO this isn't right.
    });
  });
});
```

However, that last expect() isn't doing the right thing.
Any suggestions on how to test that the `<select>` loads the right information and displays it?

Comment: Is the `dimension` the directive containing that template? Can you paste the code of the directive?

Comment: Yes, dimension is the directive that contains the template.

Comment: Can you post the code of your directive?

Comment: Directive code posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see three issues with your test code:

- You're not calling `$httpBackend.flush`, therefore not simulating an HTTP response;
- You're not triggering a digest cycle, so Angular isn't rendering the markup of your directive.
- You're trying to count how many `select` are getting rendered, but it'll always be only one. You should count how many `option` are getting generated instead.

All of them are easily solved (I've changed your code a little bit to make clear what's happening):

```
describe('directive', function() {
  var $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp.directives');

    inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    });
  });

  it('should load select\'s options from xhr on render', function() {
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      // Arrange
      $httpBackend.expectPOST('url').respond(["Item 1", "Item 2"]);
      var element = $compile('<dimension ng-model="inputs.model" url="url">Dimension</dimension>')($rootScope);

      // Act
      $httpBackend.flush(); // Simulates a response
      $rootScope.$digest(); // Triggers a digest cycle

      // Assert
      expect(element.find('option').length).toBe(2); 
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cFtC6DO33EVv5IeW4LNA?p=preview) script with the above test working.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Looks like I need to learn about the digest cycle a bit more.

Comment: No problem. Testing directives can be a little tricky because we need to manually do some things that Angular would automatically do in the browser (like triggering a digest cycle) or things that simply don't work outside the browser's sandbox (like simulating keystrokes).